# How does IncoherentInstances work?

Tags: haskell, ghc, typeclass

Playing around with [some code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8369267/208257):

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances, OverlappingInstances #-}

class Arity f where
  arity :: f -> Int

instance Arity x where
  arity _ = 0

instance Arity f => Arity ((->) a f) where
  arity f = 1 + arity (f undefined)
```

Without `IncoherentInstances`:

```
ghci> arity foldr
blah blah ambiguous blah blah possible fix blah
ghci> arity (foldr :: (a -> Int -> Int) -> Int -> [a] -> Int)
3
ghci> let f x y = 3 in arity f
2
ghci> arity $ \x y -> 3
2
```

If we add `IncoherentInstances` to the list of pragmas, then it can handle `foldr` without needing a monomorphic type signature, but it gets the wrong answer on lambdas:

```
ghci> arity foldr
3
ghci> let f x y = 3 in arity f
2
ghci> arity $ \x y -> 3 -- should be 2
0
```

What is the black magic behind Incoherent Instances? Why does it do what it does here?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Well this is quite complicated. Lets start with the ambiguous error:

```
<interactive>:1:1:
    Ambiguous type variable `b0' in the constraint:
      (Arity b0) arising from a use of `arity'
    Probable fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
    In the expression: arity foldr
    In an equation for `it': it = arity foldr
```

Normally, without overlapping instances, when attempting to match a type against a class, it will compare the type against all instances for that class. If there is exactly one match, it will use that instance. Overwise you will either get a no instance error (eg with `show (*)`), or an overlapping instances error. For example, if you remove the `OverlappingInstances` language feature from the above program, you will get this error with   `arity (&&)`:

```
<interactive>:1:1:
    Overlapping instances for Arity (Bool -> Bool -> Bool)
      arising from a use of `arity'
    Matching instances:
      instance Arity f => Arity (a -> f)
        -- Defined at tmp/test.hs:9:10-36
      instance Arity x -- Defined at tmp/test.hs:12:10-16
    In the expression: arity (&&)
    In an equation for `it': it = arity (&&)
```

It matches `Arity (a -> f)`, as `a` can be `Bool` and `f` can be `Bool -> Bool`. It also matches `Arity x`, as `x` can be `Bool -> Bool -> Bool`.

With `OverlappingInstances`, when faced with a situation when two or more instances can match, if there is a most specific one it will be chosen. An instance `X` is more specific than an instance `Y` if `X` could match `Y`, but not vice versa.

In this case, `(a -> f)` matches `x`, but `x` does not match `(a -> f)` (eg consider `x` being `Int`). So `Arity (a -> f)` is more specific than `Arity x`, so if both match the former will be chosen.

Using these rules, `arity (&&)` will firstly match `Arity ((->) a f)`, with `a` being `Bool`, and `f` being `Bool -> Bool`. The next match will have `a` being `Bool` and `f` being bool. Finally it will end matching `Arity x`, with `x` being Bool.

---

Note with the above function, `(&&)` result is a concrete type `Bool`. What happens though, when the type is not concrete? For example, lets look at the result of `arity undefined`. `undefined` has the type `a`, so it isn't a concrete type:

```
<interactive>:1:1:
    Ambiguous type variable `f0' in the constraint:
      (Arity f0) arising from a use of `arity'
    Probable fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
    In the expression: arity undefined
    In an equation for `it': it = arity undefined
```

You get an abiguous type variable error, just like the one for foldr. Why does this happen? It is because depending on what `a` is, a different instance would be required. If `a` was `Int`, then the `Arity x` instance should be matched. If `a` was `Int -> Int`, then the `Arity ((->) a f)` instance should be matched. Due to this, ghc refuses to compile the program.

If you note the type of foldr: `foldr :: forall a b. (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b`, you will notice the same problem: the result is not a concrete variable.

---

Here is where `IncoherentInstances` comes in: with that language feature enabled, it will ignore the above problem, and just choose an instance that will always match the variable. Eg with `arity undefined`, `Arity x` will always match `a`, so the result will be 0. A similar thing is done at for `foldr`.

---

Now for the second problem, why does `arity $ \x y -> 3` return 0 when `IncoherentInstaces` is enabled?

This is very weird behaviour. This following ghci session will show how weird it is:

```
*Main> let f a b = 3
*Main> arity f
2
*Main> arity (\a b -> 3)
0
```

This leads me to think that there is a bug in ghc, where `\a b -> 3` is seen by `IncoherentInstances` to have the type `x` instead of `a -> b -> Int`. I can't think of any reason why those two expressions should not be exactly the same.

Comment: arity (\a b -> a + b) gives the correct result, I think it's an issue with the optimizer nuking dead variables (analysis is marking them as dead at least) when it probably shouldn't be.

Comment: @NathanHowell - interesting. `arity $ \a b -> const a b` yields `2`, but `arity $ \a b -> a` yields `0`.

Comment: +1 thanks for the good explanation of OverlappingInstances and IncoherentInstances.

Comment: @NathanHowell does an optimizer play any role here, though, since this is in a GHCi session?

Comment: @acfoltzer that's what it seems like, or at least ghc -O0 produces output that changes based on the liveness analysis (not sure how close that is to GHCi). https://gist.github.com/243818cd8f216bdaa09b

Comment: Seems like the "How" should be dropped from the question, then? :) My impression is that there are many people who believe IncoherentInstances is a bad idea and would not be sorry to see it gone altogether.

Comment: The bug seems to be fixed in 8.0.2.