# Haskell Overlapping/Incoherent Instances

Tags: haskell, types

I know this is code is a bit silly, but can someone explain why this `isList [42]` returns `True` whereas `isList2 [42]` prints `False`, and how to prevent this? I'd like to get better understanding of some of the more obscure GHC type extensions, and I thought this would be an interesting example to figure out.

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverlappingInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE IncoherentInstances #-}

class IsList a where
  isList :: a -> Bool

instance IsList a where
  isList x = False

instance IsList [a] where
  isList x = True

isList2 = isList

main = 
  print (isList 42) >> 
  print (isList2 42) >> 
  print (isList [42]) >> 
  print (isList2 [42])
```

Comment: Because your program is incoherent. Really, what did you *expect*?

Comment: I expected the output to be `True True`, not `True False`. Why do you expect the output to be `True False`? Why wouldn't the incoherent program return `True True`? Are you saying that there's no reason for the output, and the result is undefined, and it may actually return `True True` sometimes?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does IncoherentInstances work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8371499/how-does-incoherentinstances-work)

Comment: Try adding an explicit type signature `isList2 :: IsList a => a->Bool`.

Answer (score 15):

It's really quite simple. Let's ask GHCi what the type of `isList2` is:

```
∀x. x ⊢ :t isList2
isList2 :: a -> Bool
```

This doesn't match the `[a]` instance (even though it could, via unification), but it does match the `a` instance immediately. Therefore, GHC selects the `a` instance, so `isList2` returns `False`.

This behavior is precisely what `IncoherentInstances` means. Actually, this is a rather nice demonstration of it.

---

Hilariously, if you simply disable `IncoherentInstances`, we get exactly the opposite effect, and GHCi now says this:

```
∀x. x ⊢ :t isList2
isList2 :: [Integer] -> Bool
```

This happens because `isList2` is a top-level binding not defined using function syntax, and thus subject to the Dreaded Monomorphism Restriction. So it gets specialized to the instance it's actually used with.

Adding `NoMonomorphismRestriction` as well as disabling `IncoherentInstances`, we get this instead:

```
∀x. x ⊢ :t isList2
isList2 :: IsList a => a -> Bool
∀x. x ⊢ isList2 'a'
False
∀x. x ⊢ isList2 "a"
True
∀x. x ⊢ isList2 undefined

<interactive>:19:1:
    Overlapping instances for IsList a0 arising from a use of `isList2'
```

Which is the expected overlapping behavior, with the instance chosen based on use and complaints if the choice is ambiguous.

---

Regarding the edit to the question, I don't believe the desired result is possible without type annotations.

The first option is to give `isList2` a type signature, which prevents `IncoherentInstances` from selecting an instance too early.

```
isList2 :: (IsList a) => a -> Bool
isList2 = isList
```

You'll probably need to do the same anywhere else `isList` is mentioned (even indirectly) without being applied to an argument.

The second option is to disambiguate the numeric literals and disable `IncoherentInstances`.

```
main = 
  print (isList (42 :: Integer)) >> 
  print (isList2 (42 :: Integer)) >> 
  print (isList [42]) >> 
  print (isList2 [42])
```

In this case, there's enough information to pick a most-specific instance, so `OverlappingInstances` does its thing.

Comment: I've edited the question. Could you address how I could get the above to compile and return `False False True True`?

Comment: @Clinton: There's no *nice* way to do that, I don't think. See the edit to my answer.

Comment: @Clinton I will go a bit further and say there CANNOT be a nice way to do that. GHC must obey the open world assumption when it comes to typeclasses, and must never make a decision based on the lack of a certain typeclass. For `isList 42` to return `False` you actually NEED to violate that assumption. As you have to assume there does not exist `instance Num [a] where ...` because the existence of such a typeclass would change the answer from `False` to "it depends on which instance you pick", which is not a valid value of type `Bool`.

Answer (score 2):

The following [code](http://ideone.com/rLbJiH) does the trick without requiring `IncoherentInstances`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverlappingInstances #-}

class IsList a where
  isList :: a -> Bool

instance IsList a where
  isList x = False

instance IsList [a] where
  isList x = True

isList2 :: (IsList a) => a -> Bool
isList2 = isList

main = do
  print (isList (42 :: Int))
  print (isList [42 :: Int])
  print (isList2 (42 :: Int))
  print (isList2 [42 :: Int])
```

I'd recommend not using `IncoherentInstances`, it seems to cause a lot of trouble, as you can silently call different overloads depending on context quite easily.