# Define Equality Instance for Free Monad

Tags: haskell, equality

Given the `Free Monad`:

```
data Free f a = Var a
               | Node (f (Free f a))
```

I tried to define an `Eq` instance for it:

```
instance (Functor f, Eq (f a)) => Eq (Free f a) where
    (==) (Var x) (Var y)       = x == y
    (==) (Node fu1) (Node fu2) = fu1 == fu2
    (==) _ _                   = False
```

But that fails to compile:

```
FreeMonad.hs:17:10:
    Non type-variable argument in the constraint: Eq (f a)
    (Use FlexibleContexts to permit this)
    In the context: (Functor f, Eq (f a))
    While checking an instance declaration
    In the instance declaration for ‘Eq (Free f a)’
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Specifying a constraint/pre-condition of `(Functor f, Eq (f a))` seems odd to me (at least I don't think that I've seen it as a beginner before).

How can I define an `Eq` instance for `Free f a`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with having a constraint like `Eq (f a)`. As the error message says, you will need to enable the (harmless) `FlexibleContexts` GHC extension to do that, so add...

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
```

... to the top of your source file.

Do note, however, that `(Functor f, Eq (f a))` doesn't really reflect what you are doing in your implementation of `(==)`. Firstly, you don't need the supposition that `f` is a `Functor` here, so you can safely drop the `Functor f` constraint. Secondly, the constraints should match what you need to write the different cases. In the first case, you do `x == y`. `x` and `y` are both of type `a`, and so you need `Eq a`. For analogous reasons, the second case requires `Eq (f (Free f a))` rather than `Eq (f a)`. That means you will end up with...

```
(Eq (f (Free f a)), Eq a) => Eq (Free f a)
```

... which matches reference implementations such as the one in [`Control.Monad.Free`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/free-4.12.1/docs/Control-Monad-Free.html#t:Free).

Comment: Now I'm seeing: `Variable ‘f’ occurs more often than in the instance head
 in the constraint: Eq (f (Free f a)). (Use UndecidableInstances to permit this)`. OK to add that too?

Comment: @KevinMeredith It is OK too. The worst thing that might happen with UndecidableInstances is compilation failing if you e.g. lead the type checker to an infinite loop, but that won't happen here. The main nasty extensions that you generally should not turn on even when GHC suggests them are [OverlappingInstances](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1064232) and [IncoherentInstances](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16050566) -- those two open the doors to nonsense. You did the right thing by asking, BTW: most extensions are harmless, but you should know what they do and whether you need them before enabling.

Answer (score 2):

duplode shows how to do it with flexible contexts. If you want Haskell 2010, the usual approach is to use the `Eq1` class from `Prelude.Extras` or similar.

```
class Eq1 f where
  (==#) :: Eq a => f a -> f a -> Bool
```

Then you'd use

```
instance (Eq1 f, Eq a) => Eq (Free f a) where ...
instance Eq1 f => Eq1 (Free f) -- default instance is fine.
```

I'm not at my computer right now, so I can't test this until later.