# Polyvariadic generalised sum

Tags: haskell, polyvariadic

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3467806/864340) demonstrates a polyvariadic function that sums its arguments:

```
class SumRes r where 
    sumOf :: Integer -> r

instance SumRes Integer where
    sumOf = id

instance (Integral a, SumRes r) => SumRes (a -> r) where
    sumOf x = sumOf . (x +) . toInteger
```

I have created a generalised version of this function for all members of `Num`:

```
class (Num n) => MySumType n r where
    mySum :: n -> r

instance (Num n) => MySumType n n where
    mySum x = x

instance (Num n, MySumType n r) => MySumType n (n->r) where
    mySum x = mySum . (x +)
```

However this only works with calls like `mySum (1::Int) (3::Int) (2::Int) :: Int`. Without the type specifier on the arguments, I get this error:

> No instance for (MySumType n0 Float) arising from a use of `mySum'
>
> Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (MySumType n0 Float)
>
> In the expression: mySum 1.0 :: Float
>
> In an equation for `it': it = mySum 1.0 :: Float

What is causing this problem and how can I fix it? I suspect it is something to do with the type of integer literals being `Num a => a`. Also is there an equivalent function to the one above that does not rely on extensions? The ones used above are multiple parameter type classes and flexible instances.

Comment: The thing is, variadic functions are _in principle_ something rather un-Haskellish. Yes, you can do them, but it's obvious that it rather circumvents the rigidness of the type system, so it's no surprise that you may need more explicit signatures.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<s>I have~ not come across a compelling use case for polyvariadic functions in haskell, as of yet, that could not be solved by using a list or similar data structure. So if you think you have one beyond novelty, the reason I have played around with them, I would enjoy knowing what it is.</s> Enough examples have been given below, some of which I should have thought of while making the comment, that I have retracted my statement.

```
{-# language MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# language FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# language TypeFamilies #-}
{-# language IncoherentInstances #-}

class (Num n) => MySumType n r where
    mySum :: n -> r

instance (Num n, m~n) => MySumType n m where
    mySum x = x

instance (Num n, MySumType n r, n~m) => MySumType n (m->r) where
    mySum x = mySum . (x +)
```

Then after loading the file into ghci:

```
> mySum 1 2 4 5 6 7 :: Int
25
> mySum 1.1 2 4.6 5 6.9 7 :: Double
26.6
```

Type inference can also be your friend in some cases allowing you to drop the finial type annotation like in the following contrived case:

```
> replicate (mySum 1 2 3 4) 6
[6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6]
```

Regarding:

> Also is there an equivalent function to the one above that does not rely on extensions?

I think you are out of luck.  I would like to note that unless you have a reason to move away from GHC or stay with Haskell98 or Haskell2010 the extensions do you no harm and cause little compatibility problems since most people seem to be on GHC anyways.

### Edit: Additional explanation

Let start off explaining the difference between the simpler instances. I will be adding the postfix 2 to some of the names for implementation I provided.

```
instance (Num n) => MySumType n n where
    mySum x = x
```

If you combine this with the class declaration:

```
class (Num n) => MySumType n r where
    mySum :: n -> r
```

`mySum` has a type signature of `mySum :: (Num n) => n -> n`.  That `n -> n` is saying a 1 arity function that takes a type `n`, produces an `n` and `n` has a class of Num.

When using this `mySum` I have to specify what I give it and what it produces.

```
mySum 1 :: Int
mySum (1 :: Int)
```

will both give errors only when the input and the output type are specified will it give a result:

```
mySum (1 :: Int) :: Int
            ^       ^
            |       specify output type
            specify input type
```

produces a result( 1 in this case). This is because you have given an instance for `n -> n` but some one could later add a instance for `n -> m` such as `Int -> Double` like the following:

```
instance MySumType Int Double where
    mySum x = 2 * fromIntegral x

> mySum (1::Int) :: Int
1
> mySum (1::Int) :: Double
2.0
```

These instances each match a very narrow swath of all possible 1 arity function types.

Now lets look at the modified version

```
instance (Num n, m~n) => MySumType n m where
    mySum x = x
```

`mySum` here has the type signature `mySum :: (Num n, m~n) => n -> m` this type signature is saying for all 1 arity functions that take type `n` and produce type `m` where `n` has the class Num and `m` is equal to `n`.  Notice that this started off matching all 1 arity functions, `n -> m`, any `n` to any `m` then put contrants on it.

Now it is possible to do:

```
> mySum2 (1::Int)
1
> mySum2 1 :: Int
1
```

Once the input is specified the output is specified too. Other explanations [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11553705/haskell-equality-constraint-in-instance), [2](http://www.yesodweb.com/blog/2012/07/classy-prelude).

This does not stop us from specifiy more specific instances like `Int -> Double` like before either:

```
instance MySumType Int Double where
    mySum x = 2 * fromIntegral x

> mySum2 1 :: Int
1
> mySum2 1 :: Double
1.0
> mySum2 (1 :: Int) :: Double
2.0
```

Only the last `mySum2` is working off the `Int -> Double` instance. This is a property of `IncoherentInstances` and I think I will leave it to [another stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8371499/128583) to answer the role that `IncoherentInstances` is playing.

Comment: I think `makeHList` and `printf` are both compelling.

Comment: @PhilipJF printf is compelling, I have not heard of makeHList and a quick google search, and search of the index of the hlist package did not bring anything up. Could you link what you are referring to?

Comment: hm, I can't find it right now.  But, the basic idea is just use the same structure as printf to build HLists.  I'm sure Oleg has it in library somewhere, but I don't know what he called it.

Comment: Can you explain why my solution does not infer the types correctly?

Comment: @Dylan I added some explanation.

Comment: For a compelling use case for polyvariadic functions, see [QuickCheck](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck).