# Retrieving number of fields in Haskell record

Tags: haskell

I am representing a table to store data as a Haskell record and I was wondering if there is a function to get the number of fields given a record?

I ask as I have a type class to represent a table and one of class functions is *noOfCols*; which correspond to the number of fields in a record representing a table.

```
data Price = Price {bid=[Float], ask=[Float]}

class Table a where
   noOfCols :: a -> Int
   ...

instance Table Price where
   noOfCols t = 2
   ...
```

So the problem is that I will be constantly adding new fields so it's possible to forget to update the instance implementation of *noOfCols* when I add new columns (fields) to *Price*; i.e. leaving it to 2 when I now have 3 or more fields.

Is there a function that can provide the number of fields for a given record so I don't have to make a manual edit everytime I change the record?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is something that can be solved via various generic programming libraries. For example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable #-}

import Data.Data

data Price = Price {bid :: [Float], ask :: [Float]}
  deriving (Typeable, Data)

noOfCols :: Data a => a -> Int
noOfCols = gmapQl (+) 0 (const 1)
```

Then:

```
GHCi> noOfCols (Price [1,2] [3,4,5])
2
GHCi> noOfCols (0,0,0,0)
4
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `noOfCols` is the arity of the constructor function `Price`, i.e.

```
noOfCols = arity Price
```

See [Haskell: Function to determine the arity of functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8369114/haskell-function-to-determine-the-arity-of-functions) for ways to implement `arity` (see the accepted answer). (Note: @kosmikus is IMHO a better solution for you).

Site note: Maybe `[[Float]]` is a better model for you, i.e.

```
type Price = [[Float]]

bid :: Price -> [Float]    
bid = (!! 0)

ask :: Price -> [Float]
ask = (!! 1)

noOfCols :: Price -> Int
noOfCols = length
```